# How to find polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with small coefficients, such that $f(m) = 0 \pmod{n})$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $n$ be an integer number, such that $n= p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k$, where $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$ are not necessarily distinct prime numbers and $k>2$. Also, let $m$ be a given natural number.

Are there any  polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$,  with small coefficients, such that $f(m) = 0 \pmod{n}$?

Note: When $n=p_1p_2$, where $p_1, p_2$ are distinct prime numbers, we can construct $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, using base-$m$ method or other introduced methods in Number Field Sieve.

Comment: What is the constrain of the degree of f(x)? If we allow the degree to be $O(log(n))$ then we can construct a polynomial with coefficients in {-1,0,1} such that $n|f(m)$.

Comment: To show this fact, let us consider $S_r$ to be the set of all polynomials of degree at most r with coefficients in {0,1}. The size of $S_r$ is $2^r$. By the pigeonhole principle, if $2^r>n$ then there exists two polynomials $h, g \in S_r$ such that $n|h(m)- g(m)$. We can take $f=h-g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its helped me. The degree is better to be less than 5.

Comment: If you need the degree to be less than 5, there must be some constraints on the size of the coefficients (how small do you want?) For example, if $n=O(m^5)$ and the degree is 4, then we can expect that the coefficients should be $O(m)$.